# Unable to resume terminal--vg-root!

Tags: partitioning, parted

Well, today I was trying to expand my root partition with parted. I wanted to expand it from 100G to 200G. But I fatfingured it and my system crashed. On rebooting it gave me the error:
`unable to resume terminal--vg-root`.

This error kept repeating for some time and finally it said `/dev/mapper/terminal--vg-root does not exist` and dropped to a shell prompt.

On booting with gparted live image, I found my root partition to be of 200mb.

Maybe I entered an `m` instead of `g`.
Parted warned me about data loss, but unfortunately I was in my 'retard mode' at that moment and ignored it.

I had created a dump file of my drive prior to that. So is there a way I can repair my system.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess I can answer my own question. One of my friends suggested to expand the root partition(which had been reduced to 200mb) to fill the whole disk using gparted, and it worked. I'm posting it from ubuntu right now.